# Geometry Node: manipulate a list to create n objects

Tags: geometry-nodes

In Blender 3.0, using Geometry Mode, is there a way to create a list like `[0,1,2...]` and apply various operations on it (math, zip,...) ? For instance I could use it to put 100 objects whose coordinate follows some functions, say x^2 and whose size follows another function, say 2x? (I may also be interested to add some randomness)

**EDIT**

For now, I encode lists into geometry generated using `Mesh line`, and I fake the `Map` operation using `Set Position`, but it sounds a bit weird to me.

It would also be cool to encode tuples or dictionnaires, and allow inputs from the user, for instance to accept and parse a kind of list like `[{kind='cube', color='red', spiral_pos=0.5}, {kind='monster', color='purple', spiral_pos=0.8}]`

[image]

**EDIT**

Since this question is containing two questions (lists and custom attributes), I created a new question for custom attributes [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/255759/geometry-nodes-custom-attributes-in-blender-3-0).

Comment: Yes it is a very easy basic setup. Maybe you search here or watch some beginner geometry nodes tutorials.

Comment: @Chris Well, I've been searching already (I would not have posted here otherwise), but I can't find anything relevant, maybe I'm just not using the appropriate keyword (also the fact that blender 3.0 changed a number of nodes does not make it easier). For now, I'm encoding my list using the `z` position in an object generated using `Mesh Line`, and I use `Set Position` + the input `Position` to fake maps... But it sounds quite dirty.

Comment: It’s totally right. Don’t know exactly what you think is dirty with that - but that’s one way to do it and it’s totally fine.

Comment: Just a hint: you can plug your value directly in scale - you don’t have to use combine vectors - if the value for xyz is the same anyway.

Comment: @Chris: well, it seems dirty because I need to store 3 values instead of 1 (so I need to stay consistent with the convention), MeshLine is semantically closer to a 3D object than a list, I need to `Separate XYZ`, I can't add more than 3 attributes (or I don't know how) and I'm stick to real attributes (I may be interested to have a string attribute), I can't ask to the user to provide itself a list like `[{kind='cube', color='red', spiral_pos=0.5}, {kind='monster', ...}]`... But if you tell me that it's the proper solution, you may have solution for custom attributes and user inputs?

Comment: well...it is not a programming language. It is a "visual" composing "thing". And it is still under heavy development. So even more great things will come ;) If you really want to work with lists, i would recommend using animation nodes or Sverchok. They really can handle lists. GN cannot do this right now.

Comment: @Chris Sure I can understand, but that's why I was asking ^^ Concerning the list provided by the user and custom attributes, am I just missing something or is there no way to provide this? Like I heard of the Spreadsheet, but I've no idea if it can be integrated with GN.

Comment: the spreadsheet until now is just a "debugging" help for us. You cannot change there anything up to now.

Comment: Oh, ok, I though it was possible to import data from external softwares or change it internally using the spreadsheet. So if I need to import stuff from an external software, I need to use python I guess?

Comment: Even with python i am not sure whether GN can do what you want….then you would have to specify a concrete example.

Comment: But the example you wrote in the question: I don’t think that is possible right now. But it is for sure possible with animation nodes.

Comment: My answer was deleted by Duarte and so i opened a new question+answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/255779/how-can-i-use-custom-attributes-in-geometry-nodes