# How can i use custom attributes in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, custom-attributes

How can i use custom attributes in geometry nodes?

If i have a custom attribute, is there a way to use it in geometry nodes and how do i do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use custom properties in GN like this:

1. create a custom property

[image]

2. add a driver like this

[image]
*<sup>Click to enlarge</sup>*

to your geometry input value:

[image]

result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice. Still feels a little bit convoluted even though it does the job. I hope the Object Info node will be expanded at one point to let users pick custom properties, or even regular metadata on the object on which the GN tree is placed, like its name.

Comment: could you explain/update the question with the new nodes ?
I can't find a way to add the driver to the geometry input value...

Comment: please ask a new question with a link to this question. I answered a lot of question here on Blender SE and i simply cannot update all answers i ever gave for every new Blender version. I hope you understand that.